# Define the associated relation $R$ to $f: N \rightarrow N$ given by $f(x)=2x+1$ and find its $ N/R$

Tags: abstract-algebra

My solution: let $ x, x_1 \in N $, to be $ x Rx_1 $ it is necessary that $ 2x + 1 = 2x_1 + 1 $ (and this equality gives the equivalence relation); the set $ N / R $ is represented by a single $ [a] _R = ( x \in N| 2x + 1 = 2a + 1)$ and that is  $[a] _R =$ $(a) $. what do you think!

Answer (score 0):

if i remember $f$ send every element of $\mathbb N$ to odd element then the image of $\mathbb N$ will be $(2k+1)\mathbb N$ so the will be two class in $\mathbb N / R$={$0,2\mathbb N $} .

Comment: if the equation $  is 2x + 1 = 2a + 1 $ this implies that $ x = a $ and therefore in my opinion the class $ [a] _R = {a} $ Maybe I'm wrong, I'm waiting for other interventions